# How to create an user welcome message in Discord using C#

Tags: c#, discord

This is my code but it doesn't work: There is no message when a user joins. How can I fix this?

```
public async Task Client_Userjoined()  
 {
     var name = Context.Message.Author.Id;
     ulong id = 447147292617736203;  
     var chnl = Client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel;  
     await chnl.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome!<@n{name}> ");

 }
```

Comment: Give details about what doesn't work and what debugging you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it in [1.0]

this is IN the dependency map but below the "handlecommand"

```
client.UserJoined += AnnounceJoinedUser; //Check if userjoined
```

This is under the dependency map

```
    public async Task AnnounceJoinedUser(SocketGuildUser user) //welcomes New Players
{
    var channel = client.GetChannel(%TextChannelID%) as SocketTextChannel; //gets channel to send message in
    await channel.SendMessageAsync("Welcome " + user.Mention + " to the server!"); //Welcomes the new user
}
```